# Issue (401 unauthorized) adding kubernetes cluster to existing Jenkins server

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I want to add a kubernetes cluster to an existing jenkins server (and migrate jobs from docker to kubernetes using named agents).

I set up the kubernetes cluster and added a serviceaccount like for a Jenkins instance running on the same kubernetes (which I find much easier to figure out).

#[service-account.yml](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/src/main/kubernetes/service-account.yml)

```yml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["events"]
  verbs: ["watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
```

I execute `kubectl create -f service-account.yml`
then
`kubectl -n devops-tools create token jenkins-admin`
the output of which I copy to the relevant Jenkins credential

Then I set up a job and I always get 401 unauthorized. Do I need to add something else to the serviceaccount when i want to use the token from outside the cluster?

> Caused: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://10.10.0.247:6443/api/v1/namespaces/devops-tools/pods. Message: Unauthorized. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=401, details=null, kind=Status, message=Unauthorized, metadata=ListMeta(_continue=null, remainingItemCount=null, resourceVersion=null, selfLink=null, additionalProperties={}), reason=Unauthorized, status=Failure, additionalProperties={}).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the namespace is `devops-tools`.

### Creating an authentication token for an external Jenkins (ie. not deployed inside the kubernets cluster)

1. Create the serviceAccount
   `kubectl create serviceaccount jenkins -n devops-tools`
2. Create the role yaml file:

   ```yml
    ---
    kind: Role
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: jenkins
    rules:
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["pods"]
      verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["pods/exec"]
      verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["pods/log"]
      verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["secrets"]
      verbs: ["get"]
   ```
3. Apply the role:
   `kubectl apply -f jenkins-role.yaml -n devops-tools`
4. Create the role yaml file:

   ```yml
    ---
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: RoleBinding
    metadata:
      name: jenkins
      namespace: devops-tools
    roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: Role
      name: jenkins
    subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: jenkins
   ```
5. Apply the role:
   `kubectl apply -f jenkins-rolebinding.yaml -n devops-tools`
6. Create the token in the same namespace (you may have clashes in names - serviceaccoutns created in e.g. the `default` namespace):
   `kubectl create token jenkins -n devops-tools` (copy this jwt token)
7. Create a new credential in your external Jenkins of type `secret text` with the token as copied from the last step

### Verification of the token

The token is a JWT so you *can* base64-decode it or use https://jwt.io to verify it.

Here is a curl example (linux) to test it out (replace the namespace and url as appropriate):

```sh
export JENKINS_TOKEN=PASTE.TOKEN.HERE

curl --location --request GET 'https://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/devops-tools/pods' \  
--header 'Authorization: Bearer $JENKINS_TOKEN'
```

### References

- https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/kubernetes-plugin-authenitcation-to-a-remote-kubernetes-cluster
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens